# Python Printing a function

Tags: python, dictionary

Im trying to Figure out what this program will print and i am having trouble with what the function would actually print

```
def main():
d = {1 : "car",
     2 : "house",
     3 : "boat",
     4 : "dog",
     5 : "kitchen"} 

L = list(d.keys()) #i know that here a list L is created with values [1,2,3,4,5]
i = 0 
while i < len(L):# while i is less than 5 because of length of list L
    k = L[i]     # k = l[0] so k == 1
    if k < 3 :   # if 1 < 3
     d[ d[k] ] = "zebra" d[ d[1] ] = #zebra so it adds zebra to the dictionary key 1    #right?

    i += 1      # here just i += 1 simple enough and while loop continues
                # loop continues and adds zebra to dictionary key 2 and stops
 for k in d :   
    print(k, d[k]) #This is were im having trouble understanding how everything is printed

main()
```

Comment: `d[ d[k] ] = "zebra"`, adds `('car', 'zebra'), ('house', 'zebra')` to the dictionary.

Comment: Python dictionaries have no set order; that the keys come out in sorted order *in this case* is a implementation happistance; a happy coincidence by virtue of integers hashing mostly to themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a dictionary's keys by using `for elem in testDict`, the code just does that and fetches the values for each key and prints it. If you were confused about the order, then do note that Dictionaries have no order, so, the keys and values don't get printed in any order.

Something like :

```
>>> testDict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> for elem in testDict:
print('Key: {}, Value: {}'.format(elem, testDict[elem]))


Key: a, Value: 1
Key: c, Value: 3
Key: b, Value: 2
```

**UPDATE** - The code prints `'car', 'zebra'` and the like because, when the for loop encounters a key value less than 3, which is `1, 2` for your dictionary, then, `d[1]` and `d[2]` yield `"car"` and `"house"`, which are then initialised as keys with the value `"zebra"` using `d['car'] = 'zebra'` and `d['house'] = 'zebra'`, hence the result.

Comment: Yea this makes sense but when i run the program i get 1 : car 2: house etc. then i get car zebra and house zebra i want to know why those last two lines are being printed

Comment: @user2671024 : Added the explanation in the update. Still have any more issues? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {
    1 : "car",
    2 : "house",
    3 : "boat",
    4 : "dog",
    5 : "kitchen"
} 

for key, value in d.items():
    print (key, value)

for key in d.keys():
    print (key, d[key])

for key in d:
    print (key, d[key])
```

The last two loops are equivalent.

> i want to know why those last two lines are being printed

The first time through the loop:

```
k=1
```

so d[k] is equivalent to

```
d[1]
```

so

```
d[ d[k] ]
```

is equivalent to

```
d[ d[1] ]
```

and

```
d[1] is "car"
```

so that gives you

```
d[ 'car' ]
```

and the code does this:

```
d[ 'car' ] = 'zebra'
```

Comment: _"The last two loops are equivalent"_ - not quite - in py27, one allocates a new list containing the keys, which is undesirable. In py27, you want `.iteritems()` and `.iterkeys()`

Comment: @Eric, as is typical of people on SO, they do not know who their audience is.